# Qml how restoring of bindings works?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I trying to understand how bindings works when dynamic objects are used. And don't understand anything.

In code bellow I have "static" bindings:

```
property bool flag1: cfg_flag1
```

and create dynamic binding that set flag1 to `true`,
then I destroy binding and make sure that it really destroyed (via logs),
after that I trigger initial binding, but looks like binding restoring doesn't work, it prints:

```
qmlscene /tmp/Test.qml
qml: set flag1 to true
qml: buggon1 cliecked
qml: end of clicked
qml: destroyed
qml: timer trigger
```

So `restoreMode: Binding.RestoreBinding` doesn't restore previous binding or I missed something?

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "red"

    property bool flag1: {
        console.log("set flag1 to", cfg_flag1);
        return cfg_flag1;
    }
    property bool cfg_flag1: true

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "flag1: " + flag1.toString() + ", cfg_flag1 " + cfg_flag1.toString()
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 1000
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: {
            console.log("timer trigger");
            cfg_flag1 = false;
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        text: "button 1"
        onClicked: {
            console.log("buggon1 cliecked");
            let temp = cmpBinding.createObject(rect, {
                "target": rect,
                "property": "flag1",
                "value": true,
                "restoreMode": Binding.RestoreBinding,
            });
            temp.Component.onDestruction.connect(function() { console.log("destroyed"); });
            temp.destroy();
            console.log("end of clicked");
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: cmpBinding

        Binding {
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your Binding object code. As for the question, I guess that `Binding.RestoreBinding` (that is default value) restores binding on the same instance. In your case you delete it and create another instance.

Comment: @folibis This is full code, you can run it via `qmlscene`. Not sure what do you mean by providing binding code.

Comment: ah, I see you create its properties from the `createObject` call, missed that.

Comment: What about https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#binding-method?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is OK. This is just another bug of `Binding` =/.

To make it work, you can add

- `"when": true` to list of properties for `temp`
- `temp.when = false;` on `temp`'s destruction

Here is your edited code

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Rectangle {
    id: rect
    width: 100
    height: 100
    color: "red"

    property bool flag1: {
        console.log("set flag1 to", cfg_flag1);
        return cfg_flag1;
    }
    property bool cfg_flag1: true

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "flag1: " + flag1.toString() + ", cfg_flag1 " + cfg_flag1.toString()
    }

    Timer {
        id: timer
        interval: 1000
        repeat: false
        onTriggered: {
            console.log("timer trigger");
            cfg_flag1 = false;
        }
    }

    Button {
        anchors.top: parent.top
        text: "button 1"
        onClicked: {
            console.log("buggon1 cliecked");
            let temp = cmpBinding.createObject(rect, {
                "target": rect,
                "property": "flag1",
                "value": true,
                "restoreMode": Binding.RestoreBinding,
                "when": true
            });
            temp.Component.onDestruction.connect(function() { temp.when = false; console.log("destroyed"); });
            temp.destroy();
            console.log("end of clicked");
            timer.start();
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: cmpBinding

        Binding {
        }

    }
}
```